# openssl enc is having troubles with single quote ( ' )

Tags: ruby, openssl

I'm trying to Base 64 encrypt a password using opessl enc, but when the password includes a single quote it doesn't return anything.

Do you know a option that i can use to avoid this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: a sample would only be fair, not?

Answer (score 1):

Probably shell quoting is tripping you up

```
sehe@meerkat:~$ base64 <<< "this isn't a problem"
dGhpcyBpc24ndCBhIHByb2JsZW0K
sehe@meerkat:~$ base64 <<< 'this isn't working'
```

also with openssl:

```
sehe@meerkat:~$ echo -n "I don't see the \" problem \"" | openssl enc -e -a 
SSBkb24ndCBzZWUgdGhlICIgcHJvYmxlbSAi
```